# Background page not detecting string in URL properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to set up a listener in my background page that will increment a counter when a tab is updated with "nytimes.com" in its URL (eventually I want it to increment when a tab is updated with "NYTimes.com" in its title, but first things first). My code is as follows:

```
// storage for counts
if (localStorage.getItem('nyt') == undefined || localStorage.getItem('nyt') == NaN)
{
    localStorage.setItem('nyt', 0);
}

// turn the value from localStorage into an incrementable int
var nytCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('nyt'));

// listen for changed tabs and check URL
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    debugger;
    var url = changeInfo.url;
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && url && url.indexOf("nytimes.com") !== -1) {
        localStorage.setItem('nyt', ++nytCount);
    }
});
```

The background page is declared as follows in manifest.json:

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
...
```

I've also tried declaring "persistent" as true, and that doesn't seem to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently completed my first extension, so I don't know if I have the best way, but I was able to check for the host in a tab using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()`.

I had to add `"webRequest"` to `permissions` in the `manifest` file, and when there was a match, it would fire a callback that could then react as needed.  In my case I redirected the browser, but in yours can increase your counter.

I wrote [this blogpost about how I created my chrome extension](http://jdstraughan.com/2013/02/07/nonews-part-2-the-source/), hopefully it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. In another post I was told that the best way to do it is probably with chrome.tabs, so hopefully someone will give me some guidance on that front.

Comment: I actually seem to have gotten it - here's what I used, if you're interested:

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(url, changeInfo, Tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
    {
        var title = tab.title;
        
        if (title.indexOf("NYTimes.com") != -1 && changeInfo.status == "complete")
        {
            localStorage.setItem('nyt', ++nytCount);
        }
    });
});